# How to compile tldTracker with opencv contrib module

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I am trying to implement a tldTracking by taking a video stream and trying to track an object "live". 
After downloading and including the tracking module in "opencv contrib" from github, I still experience compilation issues. 
The issue is coming not from my own code, but from the opencv contrib code. Specifically, in the tldDetector.cpp file there is a use in ocl, and the compiler (vs2015) cannot seem to recognize this class.

For the following line in tldDetector.cpp (line 125):

```
cv::ocl::ProgramSource src = cv::ocl::tracking::tldDetector_oclsrc;
```

I get the following compilation error message:

> Error C2039 'tldDetector_oclsrc': is not a member of 'cv::ocl'

And indeed, in the ocl.hpp header file that is included there is no mentioning of tracking inside the ocl namespace. I was thinking this might originate from the changes made in openCV 3.0, but I cannot seem to find the source for this problem. 
Any ideas on what am I missing? How can I get this to compile?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Disable [openCL and other gpu](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_fedora/py_setup_in_fedora.html) related modules and see if it compiles.

```
cmake -D WITH_OPENCL=OFF -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpu=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuarithm=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpubgsegm=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpucodec=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpufeatures2d=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpufilters=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuimgproc=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpulegacy=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuoptflow=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpustereo=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gpuwarping=OFF ..
```